# how to add admin email notification on order timein opencart 1.5.6

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module

i am create new module for icici bank payment getway. its work good but one problem in complete order after not get any email in admin side. what a code or function  i include in my script to get email on my admin email id.

```
catalog\controller\payment\payeezy.php
```

on page

```
    $subject  = 'Payment Status';
    $text     = "Dear ".$order_info['firstname']." ".$order_info['lastname']. "\n\n";
    $text    .= "We have received your order, Thanks for your Ccavenue payment.The transaction was successful.Your payment is authorized.". "\n";
    $text    .= "The details of the order are below:". "\n\n";
    $text    .= "Order ID:  ".$order_id. "\n";
    $text    .= "Date Ordered:  ".$order_info['date_added']. "\n";
    $text    .= "Payment Method:  ".$order_info['payment_method']. "\n";
    $text    .= "Shipping Method:  ".$order_info['shipping_method']. "\n";
    $text    .= "Order Total:  ".$order_info['total']. "\n\n";
    $to       = array(1=>$order_info['email'],2=>$this->config->get('config_email'));
    $mail = new Mail(); 
    $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
    $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
    $mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
    $mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
    $mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
    $mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
    $mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');         
    $mail->setTo($to);

    $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
    //$mail->setReplyTo($this->request->post['email']);

    //$mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
    $mail->setSender($order_info['store_name']);
    $mail->setSubject($subject);
    // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
    $mail->setText(html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    // END OF IMPORTANT PART
    $mail->send();
```

Comment: $mail->setSender($order_info['store_name']); is email ?

Comment: yes, mail will send on customer email id but not receive on store owner email id